# How to get which checkbox was CLICKED in a checkboxlist in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page with a checkboxlist containing a bunch of checkboxes.

I would like to know the index of which checkbox was CLICKED. I am not looking for which checkbox was CHECKED since that can be retrieved by using SelectedIndex.

Say for example I have the following code

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="_CheckBoxList" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">Apple</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Banana</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Selected="True">Orange</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

So if the user clicks on the Orange checkbox (which would basically deselect it), I would like the output to be 2 since Orange was CLICKED.

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use javascript for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to capture onclick event of those items, and store the values in a hidden html field. Then you could use it either from code behind or client side.

If you'd like every click to fire an event on the backend, you can use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know this on the Server side.  If you want to know it on the client side, it's fairly simple.

Click information isn't automatically passed to the server.  You'd have to capture it with Javascript and pass it back, either through storing it in a hidden field or with an Ajax call.

I am assuming you want to know their final click, not all the checkboxes they might have checked and unchecked.  If you just need to know what option was the final click, you can get by with a single hidden field.  If you need to know all the clicks that take place before the final postback, things get complicated.  You could store one hidden field per checkbox.  There are probably other ways to do that, though.

Comment: Ann, How can I get the index of last clicked checkbox in javascript? That is, var index = document.getElementById('_CheckBoxList').???? will give me the index?

Comment: The easiest approach would probably be to use jQuery, if you aren't already.  You would want to attach an event handler to all of the checkboxes in whatever HTML container the check box list is rendered as.  (I think it will be a DIV, but I'm not sure.)  Your event handler will stash the index somewhere.  The "somewhere" could be a hidden field (if you plan to post it back).  Whenever you need to know what that final value is (the index), reference the value of that hidden field:  its current value will be the final check box checked.

Comment: I realize that that's a pretty high-level summary, but space is limited, and each individual step is fairly straightforward in jQuery.